# Change of Variables: double integration convert from polar to Cartesian coordinates

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, change-of-variable

Convert the following to rectangular (Cartesian) coordinates:

$$\int_\pi^{5\pi/4} \int_0^{-5sec \theta} r^3\sin^2 \theta drd\theta$$

I understand that the equation $r^2\sin^2 \theta$ should be $y^2$ when converted to rectangular coordinates, but I am struggling with determining the new rectangular bounds for the integrals.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi! What happen with the other $r$? because $r^2 sin^2=y^2$ but there are other $r$.

Answer (score 2):

Note 
$$
r=-5\sec \theta\implies r\cos\theta=-5
$$
or in cartesian coordinates, $x=-5$. Note also your angular coordinate sweeps out the region bounded by this line and and the $x$ axis, but only 45 degrres worth.

Then, your region is the triangle bounded by 
$$
x=-5,y=x,y=0
$$
So your new integral is 
$$
\int_{-5}^0\int_x^0y^2\mathrm dy\mathrm dx=\int_{-5}^0\frac{-x^3}{3}\mathrm dx=\frac{5^4}{12}
$$

Comment: @jbmathfiend certainly, glad i could help

Comment: Hi! What happen with the other $r$? because $r^2 sin^2=y^2$ but there are other $r$.

Comment: When you write integrals in polar coordinates $dxdy\mapsto rdrd\theta$, this is the jacobian

Comment: I get it. So doing the opposite, from Polar to Cartesian, the jacobian is suppressed. Right? Thanks!

Comment: That’s correct!